# Good example of combining WPF + WCF + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, entity-framework, azure

I am planning on creating a new data-driven Client/Server application with the flexibility to have WPF, Silverlight, and mobile clients.  I am already well versed in WPF and need to learn how to implement the back end.  Everything I've read is pointing me toward using WCF + Entity Framework.

I have yet to find a realistic example of combining these three technologies.  I want to use WPF's databinding to be able to easily bind to database objects in a way that avoids as much procedural code as possible.

I looked at [this](http://prismtutorial.codeplex.com/) example based on Prism but it looks like it was never finished, it doesn't really do anything, it's basically a glorified "Hello World!"

Comment: did you try to find there : https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=WPF%20MVVM%20Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some digging and this is what I've found:

[Karl Shifflett's Netflix Stuff Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863003/Stuff-WPF-Line-of-Business-Using-MVVM-Video-Tuto)
(WPF, MVVM, Data Services)

[IssueVision](http://issuevision.codeplex.com/)
(Silverlight, MVVM, WCF RIA Services, Entity Data Model)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the walk through below which just include WPF + WCF + Entity Framework only:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161.aspx

In this walkthrough, you will create a WPF application that contains data-bound controls. The controls are bound to customer records that are encapsulated in a WCF Data Service. You will also add buttons that customers can use to view and update records.

This walkthrough illustrates the following tasks:

1. Creating an Entity Data Model that is generated from data in the AdventureWorksLT sample database.
2. Creating a WCF Data Service that exposes the data in the Entity Data Model to a WPF application.
3. Creating a set of data-bound controls by dragging items from the Data Sources window to the WPF designer.
4. Creating buttons that navigate forward and backward through customer records.
5. Creating a button that saves changes to data in the controls to the WCF Data Service and the underlying data source.

Answer (score 3):

[Demonstrates WPF, MVVM, WCF, WF and Entity Framework 6.0](https://layersample.codeplex.com/) maybe a good demo for you. and there are other Layered Architecture Samples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2010, then it might be worth your time to look at WCF Data Services. Here's an article about it:

[Entity Framework 4.0 and WCF Data Services 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336128.aspx)

The article also has a link to a code sample, but I'm not familiar with Silverlight and unable to run it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to connect my WPF application using the following examples:

Getting Started with WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) – Running and Debugging Quickly -https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/10/18/getting-started-with-wcf-windows-communication-foundation-running-and-debugging-quickly/

WCF Programming – How to write a client app that connects to a WCF Service
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/10/28/wcf-programming-how-to-write-a-client-app-that-connects-to-a-wcf-service/